# OData: How to return a singleton?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, singleton, odata

Using OData v4 I created a Singleton

```
builder.Singleton<Company>("BluAndYellow");
```

There is a function, that shall return that singleton

```
        builder.Namespace = "Workflow";
        builder.EntityType<Employee>()
            .Action("Hire")
            .Returns<Company>();
```

This throws an exception

> The EDM type 'Services.WebAPI.Company' is already declared as an
>   entity type. Use the method 'ReturnsFromEntitySet' if the return type
>   is an entity.

However, when using `ReturnsFromEntitySet` I am required to reference an entity set, which of course doesn't exist for a Singleton.

What is the right way to return a Singleton from a Funtion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frank

So far, return a singleton form a function/action is considered meaningless. Because, Singleton is a special entity. It has the certain identification, for example the 'Uri`. Users can always query the singleton from such certain 'ID'.
Therefore, neither ODL, nor Web API OData doesn't support to return a singleton from a function/action. Besides, *Delete* a singleton is also considered meaningless.

Hope it can help you. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you Sam. It's not what I was hoping for, but at least I know I don't need to research any further.